# How do I make a brush more rough?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, paint.net

I am trying to have a brush like the one on the left (Paint.net).
I have tried everything I could, but I can't make it rougher in Photoshop (right side of the picture). As you can see the Paint.net brush is a lot less transparent and more rough, thus producing more blackness then the one in Photoshop.

Any way to adjust the one in Photoshop to look like the one in Paint.net? It's basically the default Paintbrush at size 1 in Paint.net.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One pixel wide brush can have spacing and you can move it too fast in Photoshop. Goto the Brush panel, remove all fine properties, also spacing in brush tip options. If you draw slowly you get the same as in Paint.NET

[image]

For sharp non-antialiased 1 px wide track use no brush, use the Pencil.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really close to the one in Paint, but as you said - I'd have to draw slowly and yeah that's really not something I can do and then follow up the line a few more times just for the pixels to connect. Guess I'll have to use Paint then :/

Comment: Actually after playing with it for a while more I managed to just get it perfect. Thanks once again!